# (In starship) How do I hide the right prompt if the shell is small?

Tags: shell, prompt

I have 3 monitors, but one is tiny. My terminal is on the tiny monitor, and starship is configured for a massive right prompt. Can I hide this based on terminal size? I'm aware that the right prompt hides when stdin would overlap with it, but can I make this always happen?

Comment: If you don't get any answers here try here: https://github.com/starship/starship/discussions